# how to insert value into data base using jquery/ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

index.php

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".submit").click(function(){
var formname = $(this).parents("form").attr("id");
            cname = $("#"+formname+" #cname").val();
            name = $("#"+formname+" #name").val();
            fname = $("#"+formname+" #fname").val();
            email = $("#"+formname+" #email").val();
            phone = $("#"+formname+" #phone").val();
            x = $("#"+formname+" #x").val();
            xii = $("#"+formname+" #xii").val();
            qualify = $("#"+formname+" #qualify").val();
            $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              data:{"cname":cname,"name":name,"fname":fname,"email":email,"phone":phone,"x":x,"xii":xii,"qualify":qualify},
              url:"enquiry.php",
              success:function(data){
                $("#"+formname+" #msg").html(data);
              }
            });
          });
        });
    </script>
<a href='#' id='enquire' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $id; ?>">Enquire</a></span>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $id; ?>" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="msg"></div>
        <form method="post" name="formid<?php echo $id; ?>" name="formname<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter Your Father's Name"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="x" id="x" placeholder="Enter Your X Percent">
            <input type="text" name="xii" id="xii" placeholder="Enter Your XII Percent"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="qualify" id="qualify" placeholder="Enter Your Qualifying Exam(Optional)"><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" class="submit" name="" id="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

enquiry.php

```
<?php 
    $cname = $_POST['cname'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $x = $_POST['x'];
    $xii = $_POST['xii'];
    $qualify = $_POST['qualify'];
    $sql = "insert into student_enquiry(college_name,name,father,email,phone,x_percent,xii_percent,qualify)values('$cname','$name','$fname','$email','$phone','$x','$xii','$qualify')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    if($result == true)
    {
        echo "<p style='color:green;text-align:center;'>your data has been submitted successfully</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p style='color:red;text-align:center;'>Error!</p>"
    }
?>
```

In this code I am creating a modal having form inside it and I want to insert form value into database using jquery/ajax. when I clcik on submit button it hide the modal and show nothing like successfull msg or any error msg. So, How can I do this ?please help.

Thank You

Comment: Change the button type from Submit to button, so it will not refresh

Comment: nothing when I click on submit button then model hide.

Comment: did your input get saved in the database?

Comment: Have you changed button type submit to button? Because of submit type it refresh

Comment: no,  @verhie input are not save

Comment: yes @PankajMakwana I change button type

Comment: Log the query and check you get proper data from ajax and put that query in phpmyadmin. if it successfull runs that means working properly other wise you will get error

Comment: I have check my query in phpmyadmin it work properly

Comment: @omkara : Is your ajax request received to your PHP code?

Comment: Did you get any error on php side?

Comment: Have you inckuded connection file? Because I can't see it in your code. And `$link` is there

Comment: I have got my error I forgot termination sign at the last of the enquiry.php file where I echo error msg. Thanx for every one for your support.

Comment: I am facing new challenge @pankaj i.e. as I show my modal is dynamic then it will open new form for every table row. now I can only insert starting row value but when click on next modal value are not inserting why?

Comment: when I alert var formname it display undefine @pankaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Below jquery code and html code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submit").click(function () {
        var formname = "formid"+$(this).attr("data-id");
        cname = $("#" + formname + " #cname").val();
        name = $("#" + formname + " #name").val();
        fname = $("#" + formname + " #fname").val();
        email = $("#" + formname + " #email").val();
        phone = $("#" + formname + " #phone").val();
        x = $("#" + formname + " #x").val();
        xii = $("#" + formname + " #xii").val();
        qualify = $("#" + formname + " #qualify").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {"cname": cname, "name": name, "fname": fname, "email": email, "phone": phone, "x": x, "xii": xii, "qualify": qualify},
            url: "enquiry.php",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#" + formname + " #msg").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML CODE

```
<a href='#' id='enquire' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $id; ?>">Enquire</a></span>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $id; ?>" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="msg"></div>
        <form method="post" name="formid<?php echo $id; ?>" name="formid<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter Your Father's Name"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="x" id="x" placeholder="Enter Your X Percent">
            <input type="text" name="xii" id="xii" placeholder="Enter Your XII Percent"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="qualify" id="qualify" placeholder="Enter Your Qualifying Exam(Optional)"><br/><br/>
            <input type="button" class="submit" name="submit" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Give an **id** to the form element.

```
 <form method="post" id="registration">
```

---

Submit the form as follows:

```
var formdata = jQuery('#registration').serialize();
 jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'enquiry.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formdata,
        success: function(result) {
            $("#msg").html(data);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below example for save data using ajax,

JS/CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submit").click(function(){
        cname = $("#cname").val();
        name = $("#name").val();
        fname = $("#fname").val();
        email = $("#email").val();
        phone = $("#phone").val();
        x = $("#x").val();
        xii = $("#xii").val();
        qualify = $("#qualify").val();
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          data:{"cname":cname,"name":name,"fname":fname,"email":email,"phone":phone,"x":x,"xii":xii,"qualify":qualify},
          url:"enquiry.php",
          success:function(data){
            $("#msg").html(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a href='#' id='enquire' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Enquire</a></span>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="msg"></div>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter Your Father's Name"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="x" id="x" placeholder="Enter Your X Percent">
            <input type="text" name="xii" id="xii" placeholder="Enter Your XII Percent"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="qualify" id="qualify" placeholder="Enter Your Qualifying Exam(Optional)"><br/><br/>
            <input type="button" name="" id="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Ajax File.
In this file you can get posted data and save them.

```
<?php
// Your mysql query.
$insert = mysql_query("insert into `table_name` set `field1`=''");
if($insert){
    echo "Inserted successfully !";
}
else{
    echo "Not Inserted !";
}
?>
```

Comment: what are you doing new @jaydeep mor

Comment: Not new. It is model to save data using Ajax with display success message.